# How may i escape / and other characters in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url, escaping

When i visit `http://localhost:17357/u/a%2fa/m/ssd-10` and look at `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` in Application_BeginRequest i see `http://localhost:17357/u/a/a/m/ssd-10` huh? shouldnt i get `http://localhost:17357/u/a%2fa/m/ssd-10`? i thought the point of escaping urls is so ?, &, / and other special symbols not be confused with their special meaning in urls. Maybe theres a config i need to tweak?

---

I created 4 usernames, there are

```
a?@!&ee
a?@!/&ee
as d
ｸｲﾝ
```

with the links as

```
<a href="/u/a%3f%40%21%26ee">a?@!&amp;ee</a><br>
<a href="/u/a%3f%40%21%2f%26ee">a?@!/&amp;ee</a><br>
<a href="/u/as%20d">as d</a><br>
<a href="/u/%ef%bd%b8%ef%bd%b2%ef%be%9d">ｸｲﾝ</a>
```

The last two work, but the first two i get the exceptio

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.
```

then

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Additional information: '/u/a?@!&ee' is not a valid virtual path.
```

and my page says `Bad Request`. How can i allow these usernames to work. If its impossible how can i write a workaround?

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape it again. Use `%252f` instead of `%2f`. To clarify, the URL is unencoded when the server receives it. URL encoding allows you to pass in a `/` that the server processes as a character instead of the special function that a reserved character would normally trigger. See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) page for more info.

Concerning your error with the `a?@!&ee` username, it seems almost certain that you're running into a problem that ASP.NET has with special characters (even urlencoded properly) that are not in the query string (that is, after the `?` part of the URL). Joshua Flanagan talks about it [in a blog post](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2009/04/27/asp-net-400-bad-request-with-restricted-characters.aspx), and identifies `%`, `&`, `*`, and `:` as the problematic characters.

He points to a [Dirk.Net blog post](http://dirk.net/2008/06/09/ampersand-the-request-url-in-iis7/) that offers a couple of fixes. First, you can [edit the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129) to allow restricted characters (adding a DWORD key `AllowRestrictedChars` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` and setting its boolean value to true). Or, you can ensure that you have the [.NET framework 1.1 SP1 and edit the registry to set ASP.NET VErification Compatibility to true](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;826437) (`DWORD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET VerificationCompatibility = 1`). Third, you can try setting `ValidateRequest` to false on the ASPX page. Finally, as Joshua decided to do, you can pass the information using the query string, i.e. after the `?` as ASP.Net originally (pre MVC) expected.

Comment: good answer. do you know of any other chars i need to escape twice?

Comment: Percent-encoding the percent (i.e. using `%25` instead of `%`) should cover all the cases. You can chain it as many times as you like, if a URL is going to be passed around a lot, for example `%252525252f` is escaped 5 times (4 `25`s and the original escaped `%2f`.

Comment: hey `%252f` gets me a bad request.

Comment: I just did a test, and I'm able to hyperlink to a file in a folder named `sdlk%252fsd` with `href="/sdlk%252fsd/test.txt"`, so I think you're probably running into a different problem if `%252f` is breaking the request.

Comment: I am using 3.5. I added both to the registry (dword, i double checked both again now) and `validateRequest` (lower v) has already be set to allow `unsafe` POST data. Still no luck :(

Comment: What OS are you running it on (name and 32/64 bit), and what version of IIS (version number and 32/64 bit)?

Comment: Thats probably the reason, i thought it was a .NET config (from the first link) then IIS. I am using MSVS built in web server. I would like to use IIS8 but i am long from completing development and dont have a server nor access to one.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own solution. Its nice to have a username with / but not consider as / when getting a GET request.